# Basic implementation of suffix in Go

Tags: strings, go

I'm learning string algorithms and I wanted to optimize the basic suffix algorithm which I implemented.

## suffix.go

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main(){
  str := "Hello"
  arr := []string{}
  for i:=len(str)-1; i >=0 ; i--{
    var s string
    s = s+str[i:]
    fmt.Println(s)
    arr = append(arr, s)
  }
}
```

The problem with the above code is, every time I'm creating a new string. I'm trying to avoid it but was not able to do.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to create a new string at each iteration. You can directly append the subslice to the array like this:

```
arr = append(arr, str[i:])
```

An other easy optimisation would be to create an array with the correct capacity to save an allocation at each iteration, as we know that `arr` will have the same length as `str`:

```
arr := make([]string, len(str))
```

so the code can now be rewritten like this:

```
func new() {
    str := "Hello"

    arr := make([]string, 0, len(str))
    for i := len(str) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        arr = append(arr, str[i:])
    }
}
```

Running a small benchmark comparing the `old` and the `new` implementation, we get this result:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkOld-2           3000000               553 ns/op             240 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkNew-2          10000000               127 ns/op              80 B/op          1 allocs/op
```